# What is the bold sans font used in the Boscom logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I usually use WhatTheFont for this but it's not working correctly. Is anyone able to shed some light at all?

Comment: Hi Andy, have you tried the other [identification tools](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366)?

Comment: That one is really easy. It's Gill Sans Bold.

Comment: Haha @RandyJones i wasn't aware of "WhatFontIs" i think i'll use that from now on. Thank you :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach quite right, it is :)

Comment: I think the reason WhatTheFont chokes is there is something screwy about that image. It works fine on other images. Take a screenshot of your logo, save as GIF and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This is Gill Sans bold, it is there in the default fonts too.

Comment: ...not everyone's default fonts, mind you :) Hi Gaurav, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Adding a screenshot of Gill Sans for comparison and possibly a resource where it can be bought, might improve your answer a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is the correct answer. A screen shot and link would be nice, but c'mon. This is Gill Sans. Easily google-able.